# Capture non-attribute user input in ArcGIS Pro task

Tags: arcgis-pro, for-loop, tasks

I am trying to write an ArcGIS Pro task that involves one or more data layers.  However, the exact number of layers may vary between runs. Sometimes the data may be in one file, other times there may be two or more files.

**Is it possible to get input from the user that isn't an attribute value?**

Specifically, I would like the user to be able to specify with an integer how many different layer(s) are involved, and then use that input value in a For loop containing Add Data command(s).